# Body and Div alignment in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am giving body and div same height,width.
my css is

```
 body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: maroon;
width: 1280px;
height: 670px;
margin: 0;
```

}

```
div {
background-color: yellow;
width: 1280px;
height: 670px;
```

}

and my html is

```
<body>
<div   id='slider4' class='swipe'>
<div>
<div style='display:block' >1</div>
<div style='display:none'><div>2</div></div>
</div>
```

```
</body>
```

but when i open it in firefox it display like this i dont know

size of html=size of body=size of div

then also red color is beyond yellow.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you expect? You can't set a body height, the browser will not resize itself because you want a specific window size.

Comment: i am say that though my body size is of div size then why red color is showing

Comment: Because the browser window height is bigger than 1280px => the body background color is displayed below your div. White by default, marron in your case.

Comment: use height equal to 100% for complete yellow bg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maroon shows because for backward compatibility reasons, by default the html element takes its background colour from the body element, and the viewport takes its background colour from the html element.

[The CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background) says:

> For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an
>   XHTML "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element.

and

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas

You can set the background colour of the html element to, say, "white" to stop the maroon area extending beyond the height of the body element.

Comment: +1 interesting answer. Anyways what the OP is doing is kinda strange. Why setting fixed height and width on `<body>`? Can't imagine